# In Angular, how can we handle the 404 URLs in the images?

Tags: angular

I need to handle the s3 URLs in my angular projects  but in  console, I am getting 404 errors if s3 URL is not present

Every time I redirect to page it showing 404 errors in console

Comment: provide code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example. You should create a component error like NotFoundComponent And Customize that component. Then Add a router to routing like this

```
    {
        path: '**',
        component: PageErrorComponent,
    }
```

Remember this obj must be in the last Routes